# Строку "[[(}]]" надо привести в вид '[[]]'

Tags: алгоритм

Помогите разобраться в алгоритме. Нужна принимать строку с неправильными расставленными скобками '[[{(}(})]]' '[[{}()]]'
Проверять на верность или неверность расставленных скобок я научился. через стек и остаток в нем по итогу перебора.
с какой стороны подойти к задачке, даже не представляю.
('[(])') == '()'

Comment: если применить рекурсию, тут вроде на это похоже. но вопрос, как.

Comment: А если строка `[(])` - то это `[]` или `()`? Просто немного неоднозначное задание.